# Automatic initialization of procedure pointer arrays

Tags: fortran, fortran2003, fortran2008

Is there any way to automatically initialize a constant array of procedure pointers?

I have a bunch of routines, which have to be called depending on the value of an integer variable. Instead of using a `select case` statement, I would like to use procedure pointers as given below. However, it would be nice, if I could skip the explicit initialization of the procedure pointer array, and just define it as a constant array of wrapped procedure pointers. The code below demonstrates the solution I've found, the commented lines indicate the goal, I'd like to achieve:

```
module testmod
  implicit none

  abstract interface
    subroutine subInterface()
    end subroutine subInterface
  end interface

  type :: SubPtr
    procedure(subInterface), nopass, pointer :: ptr
  end type SubPtr

  ! Would be nice to use something like this:
  !type(SubPtr), parameter :: subs(2) = [ SubPtr(sub1), SubPtr(sub2) ]

contains

  subroutine sub1()
    print *, "SUB1"
  end subroutine sub1

  subroutine sub2()
    print *, "SUB2"
  end subroutine sub2

end module testmod


program test
  use testmod
  implicit none

  type(SubPtr) :: subs(2)
  integer :: ii

  ! Would be nice to get rid of those two initialization lines
  subs(1) = SubPtr(sub1)  
  subs(2) = SubPtr(sub2)

  ! Testing procedure pointer array
  do ii = 1, 2
    call subs(ii)%ptr()
  end do

end program test
```

Comment: I was able to get rid of most of the error messages by placing the subroutines in a different module. Still, the Cray compiler reports: `The initialization expression must be a constant to be used with PARAMETER assignment for object "SUBS".` Initializing a standalone procedure pointer to one of those subroutines works well.

Comment: Initializing a standalone procedure pointer to one of those subroutines works well, but nut for a `PARAMETR` procedure pointer! For the compiler it is a syntax error to use `PARAMETER` in procedure pointer context, I don't have time to check the constraints in the standard, but it probably is not permitted to have constant procedure pointers and initialize them to an existing subroutine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this (your commented out "Would be nice..." type declaration statement) simply requires (working) Fortran 2008 support.  To be valid in a constant expression the component in a structure constructor corresponding to a pointer component may be an initialization target (7.1.12p1 3b).  For a procedure pointer component, an initialization target is an *initial-proc-target*, which permits (amongst other things) a non-elemental module procedure, which is what `sub1` and `sub2` both are.